# SQL Server Reporting Services Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence

I want to a report on how many reports is successful, how many has failed as a count with added information like the report name, the user that made the report, reason for failure, path to the report, subscriptions, schedules and also be able to view historical data to show trends.

Which tables can I use to get the data I need in order to make the report?

I have found a query that would give me part of the information I need to do this report however it is obsolete as it contains tables that is no longer found in the report server DB for sql-server 2012

Any assistance or guidance would be appreciated.

[Link to the obsolete query] https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6b35fff-2a46-46ce-bc1e-c166a4d65c2d/ssrs-notification-of-success-or-failure-of-report-generation?forum=sqlreportingservices

[Link to my previous question on this topic] [Incompatible SQL Server Reporting Services Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202690/incompatible-sql-server-reporting-services-query?noredirect=1#comment83388618_48202690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query I used to search the reporting services execution log.  Also, there are some example reports on [GitHub](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples)

```
DECLARE @all_value AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @LogStatus AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ReportFolder AS VARCHAR(450)
DECLARE @ReportName AS VARCHAR(450)
DECLARE @UserName AS VARCHAR(260)
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME

SET @all_value = '<ALL>'
SET @LogStatus = '<ALL>' --filter your execution log status here
SET @ReportFolder = '...A Report Folder Name...'
SET @ReportName = '<ALL>' 
SET @UserName = '<ALL>'
SET @StartDate = NULL
SET @EndDate = NULL



;WITH
report_users 
AS
(
    SELECT UserID, UserName, SimpleUserName = UPPER(RIGHT(UserName, (LEN(UserName)-CHARINDEX('\',UserName)))) FROM dbo.Users
)
,
report_catalog
AS
(
    SELECT    
        rpt.ItemID
      , rpt.CreatedById
      , rpt.ModifiedById
      , rpt.[Type]
      , rpt.[Name] 
      , ReportName = rpt.[Name] 
      , rpt.[Description]
      , rpt.Parameter
      , CreationDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.CreationDate, 13))
      , ModifiedDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.ModifiedDate, 13))
      , ReportFolder = SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2) 
      , rpt.[Path]
      , URL_ReportFolder = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '&ViewMode=List'
      , URL_Report = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '%2f' + rpt.[Name]
      , ReportDefinition = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), rpt.Content))  
      , HostName = Host_Name()
    FROM 
      dbo.Catalog AS rpt
    WHERE 
      1=1
      AND rpt.[Type] = 2
)
    SELECT 
      ReportPath = rpt.[Path]
    , rpt.ReportFolder
    , ReportName = rpt.[Name]
    , rpt.URL_ReportFolder
    , rpt.URL_Report 
    , URL_Report_Filtered = rpt.URL_Report + '&rs:Command=Render&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), el.[Parameters])
    , UserName = usr.SimpleUserName
    , el.[Status]
    , el.TimeStart
    , el.[RowCount]
    , el.ByteCount
    , el.[Format]
    , el.[Parameters]
    , TotalSeconds = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,(el.TimeDataRetrieval + el.TimeProcessing + el.TimeRendering),0),108)
    , TimeDataRetrieval = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,el.TimeDataRetrieval,0),108) 
    , TimeProcessing = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,el.TimeProcessing,0),108)  
    , TimeRendering = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,el.TimeRendering,0),108) 
    , OrderbyDate = CAST(TimeStart AS DATETIME) 
FROM 
    report_catalog AS rpt 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ExecutionLog AS el ON el.ReportID = rpt.ItemID
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS usr ON el.UserName = usr.UserName
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND (@all_value IN(@LogStatus) OR el.[Status] IN(@LogStatus))
    AND (@all_value IN(@ReportFolder) OR rpt.ReportFolder IN(@ReportFolder))
    AND (@all_value IN(@ReportName) OR rpt.ReportName IN(@ReportName))
    AND (@all_value IN(@UserName) OR usr.SimpleUserName IN(@UserName))
    AND (@StartDate IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),el.TimeStart,13)) >= @StartDate)
    AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),el.TimeStart,13)) <= @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be of help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view

```
Use ReportServer  
select * from ExecutionLog3 order by TimeStart DESC 


Use ReportServer  
select * from ExecutionLog2 order by TimeStart DESC
```